# Switching Website From Serif to WordPress, what will happen to recurring PayPal Donaters

Tags: wordpress, paypal, donations

I am volunteering for a non-profit and creating a new website for them. They currently use Serif Software and I am using Wordpress to build the new one. Does anyone know what will happen to the current recurring donaters when I transfer the domain over to the new site and the old one disappears?
The current subscriber button is set up using :

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
```

But I will obviously just be using a plugin on WordPress,
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In normal circumstances, as long as you are integrating the new site with the same PayPal account, then the existing subscriptions should stay the same and they should collect payments as scheduled.

However, note that if you are using Instant Payment Notification (IPN) to receive payment notification, you might face some difficulties. The IPN url that is tied to subscriptions/recurring payments cannot be changed unless if you recreate the subscriptions. But still, this will not impact the payments.
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/